# Retornar arquivo pdf de webservice com Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, meteor

**Contexto do Problema:** Há uma webservice externo, qual não faz parte do domínio da minha aplicação, que, quando acessada diretamente via browser, leva o usuário a uma página web de carregamento que trata a requisição de acordo com os parâmetros passados na url e, posteriormente,  retorna um arquivo .pdf diretamente na visualização do browser.

Eu estou trabalhando em uma aplicação que tem como objetivo realizar uma chamada a esse webservice específico e retornar um arquivo .pdf gerado por este para o usuário.

De modo a tentar obter o arquivo gerado pelo webservice, eu tentei utilizar o pacote *request* do npm da seguinte forma:

```
    var request= Meteor.npmRequire('request');
    request.get({
              url: this_nfse.link_nfse,  timeout: 1500, jar: true, encoding: 'binary'
            }
            , Meteor.bindEnvironment(function( error, response, body ){
      if(!error && response)
      {          
        //tratar resultado de acordo com o objetivo da aplicação
      }          
    }));
```

Porém o que eu obtenho no objeto body é a página html que faz a requisição de geração do arquivo .pdf ao webservice, e não o arquivo ou representação desse em si.

Obs.: tentei utilizar o pacote HTTP nativo do meteor, porém obtive o mesmo resultado.

Qualquer ajuda ou dica será muito bem vinda, muito obrigado.